# Multiple projects, same files

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms project supporting iOS / Droid.
The solution also contains the PCL and two other external references.

I'm asked to create different language versions, meaning one .ipa / .apk per language.

In every project (language) only some files have to be changed (images / props on helper classes)
Is it possible to reuse the same files from my original project and just add the different files?

I have seen it working on Windows Phone but can't get it on XF.
Any ideas ?

P.S: I want to avoid copying 4 times each project.

Regards.

Comment: that's usually not how you add multi-lang support: see https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/localization/

Comment: @Jasonnthanks for your input, I'm aware of this but they have asked for different projects, even though it's the wrong approach. There also the need for slight View customization which I don't know if it's possible thought the article you mentioned

Comment: This is an odd requirement, however, why not maintain a single code base, leverage resource files for language then set the default cultureinfo based on a compiler directive or some build variable that triggers logic to use the desired language.  Perhaps your build could also create the *_en.ipa or *_es.ipa, etc based on the desired language

Comment: @StinkyTowel I have opted out for the RESX way, however, I still can't figure out in my mind how am I going to change the application icon since it's different in every language!

Comment: Set the source of the icon in your resx file.  `<data name="ICON_PATH"><value>somepath</value></data>`.  Then update logic to use **ICON_PATH** to get the name and/or location of the icon(s).  The tradeoff is you may have to ship every potential icon with the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should use resource file, it support images

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/